# Как правильно заигнорить файл?

Tags: git, github

Есть файл `myfile.php`

Как его заигнорить? Причем тотально, чтобы про формировании репозитория на сервере, да и при последующих коммитах этого файла вообще там не было?

Если мой файл находится в папке, а .gitignore лежит в корне. Получается чтобы он игнорился нужно прописать такую маску mydir/myfile.php? Если да, то почему-то это не срабатывает, срабатывает только тогда когда залью .gitignore в папку с моим файлом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создать файл **.gitignore** и в нем вписать **myfile.php**

Comment: А если его тоже в нем же заигнорить? Ладно, работает.

Comment: а зачем? что бы было весело?

`.gitignore` как раз для того и нужен, что бы помнить список игнорируемых файлов. Но если его тоже заигнорировать, то как на другом конце узнают об этом?

Comment: @KoVadim зависит от задачи. Если некто пользуется какой-либо средой разработки, а я другой, то меня файл .gitignore под эту среду разработки не очень будет интересовать. Другое дело, если в проекте есть какие-то генерируемые или просто большие файлы (типа ресурсов для игр), включение которых в репозиторий нежелательно - в таком случае я буду хотеть содержимое файла .gitignore иметь в самом репозитории.

Comment: для локального игнора существует файл .git/info/exclude, туда прописываем файлы создаваемые ide, в .gitignore всякие кэши, директории сборки и прочее создаваемое приложением.

Comment: >> Если некто пользуется какой-либо средой разработки, а я другой, то меня файл .gitignore под эту среду разработки не очень будет интересовать.

а кто мешает их слить? и добавить комментарии. По факту в это файл заглядывают очень редко. Ну пусть болтается на 10 строк больше. Если завтра придет третий разработчик, то ему не нужно будет спрашивать правильный .gitignore.

Comment: А если мой файл находится в папке, а `.gitignore` лежит в корне. Получается чтобы он игнорился нужно прописать такую маску `mydir/myfile.php`?  Если да, то почему-то это не срабатывает, срабатывает только тогда когда залью `.gitignore` в папку с моим файлом.

Comment: `/mydir/myfile.php`

Comment: @KoVadim зачем сливать в .gitignore локальный мусор ? Существует же exclude,